# GROUP BY DAY, CUMULATIVE SUM

Tags: sql-server, linq

I have a table in MSSQL with the following structure:

```
PersonId
StartDate
EndDate
```

I need to be able to show the number of distinct people in the table within a date range or at a given date.

As an example i need to show on a daily basis the totals per day, e.g. if we have 2 entries on the 1st June, 3 on the 2nd June and 1 on the 3rd June the system should show the following result:

```
1st June: 2
2nd June: 5
3rd June: 6
```

If however e.g. on of the entries on the 2nd June also has an end date that is 2nd June then the 3rd June result would show just 5.

Would someone be able to assist with this.

Thanks

## UPDATE

This is what i have so far which seems to work. Is there a better solution though as my solution only gets me employed figures. I also need unemployed on another column - unemployed would mean either no entry in the table or date not between and no other entry as employed.

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp(CountTotal int NOT NULL, CountDate datetime NOT NULL); 

DECLARE @StartDT DATETIME

SET @StartDT =  '2015-01-01 00:00:00'

WHILE @StartDT < '2015-08-31 00:00:00'

BEGIN
   INSERT INTO #Temp(CountTotal, CountDate)
   SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT PERSON.Id) AS CountTotal, @StartDT AS CountDate     FROM PERSON 

   INNER JOIN DATA_INPUT_CHANGE_LOG ON PERSON.DataInputTypeId = DATA_INPUT_CHANGE_LOG.DataInputTypeId AND PERSON.Id = DATA_INPUT_CHANGE_LOG.DataItemId 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN PERSON_EMPLOYMENT ON PERSON.Id = PERSON_EMPLOYMENT.PersonId 

   WHERE PERSON.Id > 0  AND DATA_INPUT_CHANGE_LOG.Hidden = '0' AND DATA_INPUT_CHANGE_LOG.Approved = '1' 

   AND ((PERSON_EMPLOYMENT.StartDate <= DATEADD(MONTH,1,@StartDT) AND PERSON_EMPLOYMENT.EndDate IS NULL) 


   OR (@StartDT BETWEEN PERSON_EMPLOYMENT.StartDate AND PERSON_EMPLOYMENT.EndDate) AND PERSON_EMPLOYMENT.EndDate IS NOT NULL)

   SET @StartDT = DATEADD(MONTH,1,@StartDT)
END

select * from #Temp
drop TABLE #Temp
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by creating data where every start date is a +1 event and end date is -1 and then calculate a running total on top of that.

For example if your data is something like this

```
PersonId   StartDate   EndDate
1          20150101    20150201
2          20150102    20150115
3          20150101
```

You first create a data set that looks like this:

```
EventDate   ChangeValue
20150101    +2
20150102    +1
20150115    -1
20150201    -1
```

And if you use running total, you'll get this:

```
EventDate   Total
2015-01-01  2
2015-01-02  3
2015-01-15  2
2015-02-01  1
```

You can get it with something like this:

```
select
  p.eventdate,
  sum(p.changevalue) over (order by p.eventdate asc) as total
from
(
  select startdate as eventdate, sum(1) as changevalue from personnel group by startdate
  union all
  select enddate, sum(-1) from personnel where enddate is not null group by enddate
) p
order by p.eventdate asc
```

Having window function with sum() requires SQL Server 2012. If you're using older version, you can check other options for running totals.

My example in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5ebc5/9)

If you have dates that don't have any events and you need to show those too, then the best option is probably to create a separate table of dates for the whole range you'll ever need, for example 1.1.2000 - 31.12.2099.

-- Edit --

To get count for a specific day, it's possible use the same logic, but just sum everything up to that day:

```
declare @eventdate date

set @eventdate = '20150117'

select
  sum(p.changevalue)
from
(
  select startdate as eventdate, 1 as changevalue from personnel 
  where startdate <= @eventdate
  union all
  select enddate, -1 from personnel 
  where enddate < @eventdate
) p
```

Hopefully this is ok, can't test since SQL Fiddle seems to be unavailable.

Comment: Hi thanks for this. However what i need is a bit different. The table stores a persons employment dates, therefore i need to retrieve employment numbers at a given date or between dates. e.g. If i query at a set date of 1/6/2015 i need to know all distinct people who are in employment on that date, so start date is less and either end date is greater or is null.

Comment: See the example i have provided in my question.

Comment: I added an example how to fetch the data for one specific date. If you need range, the first one provides that, but you'll need to join the data with a dates table, so that it provides 0 record for each day.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query. The cte part is to generate a set of serial dates between the start date and end date.

```
DECLARE @ViewStartDate DATETIME
DECLARE @ViewEndDate DATETIME

SET @ViewStartDate = '2015-01-01 00:00:00.000';
SET @ViewEndDate = '2015-02-25 00:00:00.000';

;WITH Dates([Date])
AS
(
    SELECT @ViewStartDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1,Date)  
    FROM Dates
    WHERE DATEADD(DAY, 1,Date) <= @ViewEndDate
)
SELECT [Date], COUNT(*) 
FROM Dates
    LEFT JOIN PersonData ON Dates.Date >= PersonData.StartDate 
    AND Dates.Date <= PersonData.EndDate
GROUP By [Date]
```

- Replace the PersonData with your table name
- If startdate and enddate columns can be null, then you need to add
  addditional conditions to the join
- It assumes one person has only one record in the same date range

Comment: Excellent answer. What if i also want to show another column on the same query that lists all those that are not employed. e.g. where PersonId not in the table or where the end date has passed.

Comment: I think You must replace 'AND Dates.Date <= PersonData.EndDate' with 'AND Dates.Date <= isnull(PersonData.EndDate,Dates.Date)', because 'PersonData.EndDate' can be null.

Comment: @Tommy, do you mean, in another column you want to show the number of employees who are not employed on that date. is it right?

Comment: @KiranHegde i have updated my question to include a partial solution. I am hoping to adapt that to your query which doesnt require any dumping to a temp table.